# My arraylist resets when I return to previous activity on backbutton pressed

Tags: java, android

I have multiple activities. In my main activity, I have my listview within an arraylist. When I go to the second activity and press the back button on the second activity to return my main activity, my arraylist size becomes zero therefore I am losing my listview entries.

Is there any way to keep my arraylist when I go back to the previous activity?

Note: On the second activity, my code is as follows:

```
public void onBackPressed(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding `onBackPressed()` instead of just letting the default behavior happen (which would go back to the previous activity by default)? What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: where do you fill the listView?

Comment: where do you fill the listView?
I pass the data from the second activity to the main activity and view it on my main.

Comment: I am overriding it because of the stack.
If I don't override it then I will never be able to reach the main activity.

Open app: A
Go to B: A, B
Go to C: A, B, C
Press back: A, B, C, A
Press back: A, B, C
Press back: A, B, C, A 
etc...

Comment: Don't override your onBackPressed method, at least like this, then the problem goes away. You are abandoning the previous activity and creating a new one with such an onBackPressed method. Of course your list will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comments you have left I'd suggest you create a management class. This class will store all of your default values and you can update it as needed from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override onBackPressed() because the default behavior has your list retained. By overriding onBackPressed(), you are recreating MainActivity which consumes more resources as you are having two MainActivity opened (the initial in the background and the latter activated by onBackPressed ())

Comment: I am overriding it because if I open multiple activities, I get stuck in between two activities and never be able to go back to the main activity.

Comment: Erase it and press back button, you will see it will work fine